# Build and run Disabled in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

There are some applications which shows **Build and run** icon disabled which stops me from running the application.It does not happen to all applications but on a few .  It mainly occurs to me in facebook applications and a few more applications.Can anybody have an idea what could be the problem ? I have tried everything from changing the build settings etc. but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the current target is UnitTests... Can you build an run if you change targets or is the icon still disabled?

Comment: i have tried everything to making device configuration to run it in 3.2

Comment: did you see any target under "Targets" menu?

Comment: Do you mind uploading a test case project?

Comment: Close and restart the Xcode again.. Work for me, may also do for u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think those may be frameworks,static libraries. So the build and run option is disabled.

Comment: What did you mean by "frameworks" disabled run option?

Answer (score 49):

Need to fix the executable, it happens after renaming project.

> Product > Scheme > Edit scheme..

Select

> Run > Info

Set Executable is your app name, if selected None.

Comment: This is the answer people

Comment: Still relevant in 2021!

Comment: I had the same problem with XCode 14.3 on macOS 13, and this solved it.

Answer (score 9):

Try this, It's work for me.

Follow below steps to unable Build and Run in xcode

1) Go to

**Product => Scheme => Edit scheme.**

[image]

2) Select **Run option** and select **info**
[image]

3) In **Executable** if option is selected to **None** then change it to your **app name**

Hope this is help for some one.

Comment: I'm using this on Xcode 12 in 2021 and this worked for me!

Comment: @tamtam , Great ..!!!!

Answer (score 6):

That project appears to be the Sparrow audio project. It's not a stand-alone project you can run; it's a library, you need to be using it in another project to have anything to actually run.

The sparrow project includes a sample app called Scaffold which demonstrates the use of Sparrow. More info:

http://www.sparrow-framework.org/help/gettingstarted/

Also see:

http://www.sparrow-framework.org/help/documentation/

Note that you can still 'build'; it's just 'build and run' that can't be clicked.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be creating plugin or frameworks or libraries (not an Application).
So the "**Build & Run**" icon is DISABLED.(as answered by Chandan Shetty SP)

In order to enable the icon you need to specify the Application which use this plugin or framework or library whatever you are building.

To specify such application:

1. Rt. Click on "**Executables**" (in Xcode's **Groups and Files** panel)
2. Select **Add** > **New Custom Executable**
3. Then specify the **name** of application (just for display purpose) and specify the **path** of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Project menu in the menubar and change the Active Target to the target of the actual app.