# Run button was disabled in Xcode 12.2

Tags: ios, xcode12

While working continually run button is not enabling when I stop running in Xcode 12.2

[image]

Help me to fix this.

Comment: it may be helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075305/build-and-run-disabled-in-xcode

Comment: Its not working

Comment: quit xcode, restart your system or else restart your xcode and check